# Why is expression (False or False or False or True) equal to False?

Tags: python

Why return `False`?

```
def checkio(m):
    for i in range(len(m)):
        for j in range(len(m)):
            try:
                print(i, j, (m[i][j], m[i + 1][j - 1], m[i + 2][j - 2], m[i + 3][j - 3]))
                print(m[i][j] == m[i + 1][j - 1] == m[i + 2][j - 2] == m[i + 3][j - 3])
                if m[i][j] == m[i][j + 1] == m[i][j + 2] == m[i][j + 3] or \
                        m[i][j] == m[i + 1][j] == m[i + 2][j] == m[i + 3][j] or \
                        m[i][j] == m[i + 1][j + 1] == m[i + 2][j + 2] == m[i + 3][j + 3] or \
                        m[i][j] == m[i + 1][j - 1] == m[i + 2][j - 2] == m[i + 3][j - 3]:
                    return True
            except:
                pass
    return False
```

Results I'm getting:

```
0 0 (1, 1, 1, 3)
False
0 1 (5, 2, 5, 3)
False
0 2 (4, 2, 1, 1)
False
0 3 (4, 4, 4, 4)
True
False
```

Update: You are given a matrix of NxN (4≤N≤10). You should check if there is a sequence of 4 or more matching digits. The sequence may be positioned horizontally, vertically or diagonally (NW-SE or NE-SW diagonals).

Update 2: If I do `try` for each compare, all work fine, but why doesn't it work with `or`?

Update 3: Thx martineau, exception work because first part of compare have except (list index out of range) and other part not compared.

Comment: What is this function supposed to be doing? If you add some context it will be easier for someone to help you out

Comment: maybe all the other cases are throwing exceptions, and only that last one makes it to `return True`? You are hiding literally **every** exception your program can be trying to show you...

Comment: Please edit the question rather than adding the context in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: The bare `except:` may be hiding a `SyntaxError`—so you should avoid using them. Change it to `except Exception as exc:` and then add a `print(exc)` on an indented line immediately following that.

Answer (score 0):

Thx martineau, exception work because first part of compare have except (list index out of range) and other part not compared.